# Laravel message: Creating default object from empty value on update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here my route :

```
// Edit User Infos
Route::put('/edit/subscriber', 'Admin\UserController@editSubscriber')->name('/edit/subscriber');
```

Axios call :

```
axios.put('/admin/edit/subscriber', {
                        userId: this.userDetails._id,
                        newFirstName: this.tempValueFirstName,
                        newLastName: this.tempValueLastName,
                        newPhone: this.tempValuePhone,
                        newEmail: this.tempValueEmail
                    }).then(({res}) => {
                        console.log(res)
                    }).catch(({err}) => {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
```

Update function in controller :

```
public function editSubscriber() {
    $validated = request()->validate([
        'userId' => 'required',
        'newFirstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'newLastName' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'newEmail' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'newPhone' => 'nullable'
    ]);

    $user = User::find($validated['userId']);
    $user->first_name = $validated['newFirstName'];
    $user->last_name = $validated['newLastName'];
    $user->email = $validated['newEmail'];
    $user->phones = $validated['newPhone'];
    $user->name = $validated['newLastName'] . ' ' . $validated['newFirstName'];
    $user->save();
}
```

When i tried to use my update fonctionnality, the changes was updated like i want but i get this 500 error : "Creating default object from empty value".

Anyone have an idea ?
Thank's.

Comment: this is because of variable `$user` is empty, check if `$validated['userId']` is not null and there is the user with such id in the DB

Comment: @V-K $user and $validated['userId'] are not empty

Comment: it's impossible. This error points to an empty object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That due to your **$user** is not initialize correctly. 
make sure you get record which you wanted to update.

And always write down and proper condition over the variable which you are using in code after value initialize.

Also always use try catch statement to debug quickly your issue.
may be below code will be helpful for you.

```
 try {
         $validated = request()->validate([
                'userId' => 'required',
                'newFirstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'newLastName' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'newEmail' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
                'newPhone' => 'nullable'
            ]);
        if ($validated->fails()) {
            return response($validated);
        }else{

           if (!blank($user)) {
                $user = User::find($validated['userId']);
                $user->first_name = $validated['newFirstName'];
                $user->last_name = $validated['newLastName'];
                $user->email = $validated['newEmail'];
                $user->phones = $validated['newPhone'];
                $user->name = $validated['newLastName'] . ' ' . $validated['newFirstName'];
                $user->save();
            }else{
                //throw error response.
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(ExceptionMessage($ex));
    }
```